# Error while restoring the checkpoint in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I used this code to save my tensor flow model:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(session, 'model.ckpt')
```

Now when I want to restore the model using this code:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir='/Documents/')
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    else:
        print("no checkpoint found")
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Fetch argument u'save/restore_all' of u'save/restore_all' cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. ("The name 'save/restore_all' refers to an Operation not in the graph.")
```

How can I fix this and restore my session?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? The error might be caused by the fact that your `tf.Session()` doesn't have the right graph. You can check this with `sess.graph.get_operations()`, if it is empty this is bad !

Comment: You need to recreate your model graph before restoring the checkpoint, for instance, by using `tf.train.import_meta_graph`

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov. It doesn't create that error anymore. But when I want to use the loaded session I receive this error: ValueError: Cannot use the default session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph. Pass an explicit session to eval(session=sess).

Comment: Thanks @OlivierMoindrot. I checked the sess.graph.get_operations(). It's not empty.

Comment: it sounds like you have more than one session. Try to only create one session to avoid such errors